# Как запустить Ajax запрос в цикле?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Как при первом успешном запросе, запустить другой запрос по следующему элементу из массива ?

php

```
$arr = array(1, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12);
```

js

```
$(function(){
$(".buton").click(function(){
    var id = "<?php echo $arr[0]; ?>";
    $.ajax({
        url: "Ajax.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {id: id},             
        success: function(html){

        if (html == 1){ // Если запрос успешный и ответ равен == 1.
               // Вполняем следующий Ajax запрс.
        }else{  
              alert("Ошыбка !!!"); 
        }
      }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: боже, какой ужас.

Comment: У вас что, php работает на стороне клиента?

Comment: Я php код привел для примера какие данные передаются через ajax запрос.

Comment: Может я не правильно задал вопрос или объяснил не так  а тут началось какой ужас, начали ставить минусы. Что за люди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sendRequestEachValue = function (values) {

    var newValues = values,
        value = newValues[0];

    newValues.splice(0, 1); // удаляем элемент который будем отправлять

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'url',
        data: {
            id: value
        },
        success: function (res) {
            if (newValues.length > 0) {
                sendRequestEachValue(newValues); // если элементы в массиве остались, то отправим запрос еще раз
            }
        }
    });
};


$('.button').on('click', function () {

    var values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

    sendRequestEachValue(values);
});
```

Comment: Как ету функцию по клику на кнопку  .buton запустить, пробовал так: $(".buton").click(function(){
   sendRequestEachValue([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
}); но не работает.

Comment: @saturn Обновил ответ. Почему не работает? Может есть ошибки в консоле браузера?

Comment: @saturn ставь брекпоинт. вызывается вообще функция или нет?